# Replace text position in python

Tags: python

I know how to replace things in python I already do it but this one I can't get it working and can't find anything.

I already repleace something like this:

```
SomeVar.replace("-", "/")
```

But now I want to switch position of text where between a `/` or a  `-` `_` Is, Like this:

This is what I have

```
text1/text2
```

And this is what I need

```
text2/text1
```

The Problem here is I have a Placeholder from an API here like `{MyText}` So We don't know before what `text1` or `text2` will be.

I tried

```
a = PosibleText1
b = PossibleText2
c = {MyText}
c.replace(a, b)
```

The Problem here It replaces only the text with an other but don't switch the postion of text around the `/` like `text1/text2` to `text2/text1`

The other big problem is, I have houndres of different possible text Outputs in the {MyText} Placehoder.

There need to be something that can identify `/` and say switch postions of text before and after `/` whatever the text is. If someone has an Idea Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable, so you do not switch the places, but create a new one. This is how it could be done:

```
# Split with the "/"
s = "text1/text2".split("/")
Out[2]: ['text1', 'text2']

# Create a new string
new = s[1] + "/" + s[0]
```

It can be generalize with as many `text_i` separate by i `/` as you want.

Comment: You should rather to the `split` once then use the same result.

Comment: This looks good but I don't know what text it will be I get it from {MyText}

Comment: @vonNiklasson Yes of course, I wrote that quite fast, with copy / paste.

Comment: @ZelaMedia It doesn't matter? It will be split around the `"/"`, no matter what the text is. Or do you mean the separator can be something else than `/`?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand your problem correctly. To swap the position of any sequence of non-space characters surrounding a slash, you can use a regex:

```
import re
s = "a/b 3/4 hello/goodbye blah blah this/again"
print(re.sub(r"([^\s/]+)/([^\s/]+)", r"\2/\1", s))
```

Output:

```
b/a 4/3 goodbye/hello blah blah again/this
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string with `'/'` into a list and the unpack it to the `str.format` method but with the items in reverse order for output:

```
c = '{1}/{0}'.format(*c.split('/'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string with `'/'` into a list and the join the list with `'/'` after reversing it:

```
c = '/'.join(c.split('/')[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the format method to do that, like that for example:

```
c = '{}/{}'.format(b, a)
```

Comment: So the `{}` Is for the {MyText} ? Can you make a more clear example I think this could work. Problem is in your Example you have `{}/{}` I have only one {MyText} where text1/text2 comes out

Comment: No, no, the c variable is where the string will be stored.
the `{}/{}` are where the two parameters of format will be written.

So imagine your variable are :

`a = 'text1'
b = 'text2'
c = 'text1/text2'`

if you do :

`c = '{}/{}'.format(b, a)`

you will get :

`print(c)
'text2/text1'`

Comment: Can you check if I did this wrong pelase: `c = '{MyText}'
                    c = '{}_{}'.format(b, a)  print(c)` the Program don't evan start  when I do this

Comment: I don't think you made any error, but i don't really understand what is the problem with your `c = '{MyText}'` variables

Comment: {MyText} is from an API where Hounreds of different Text combinations can come thats why I said we don't know before if it will be `text1/text2` or `text4000/text9999`

Comment: thats why you have to parse to get the two text